# Как избавиться от ошибки ValueError в Python?

Tags: python

При вводе пустого или буквенного значения в строке `float(raw_input())` возвращается ошибка `ValueError`; что нужно сделать, чтобы она не появлялась, а запрос повторялся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

raw_input() принимает ввод с клавиатуры.
float() это цифровое значение, следовательно рас вы оборачиваете raw_input() то вводить нужно только цифры.
Вот ещё варианты использование raw_input():

```
>>> int(raw_input("Input int (43): "))
Input int (43): 44 #ВВодим 44   
44
>>> str(raw_input("Input str (text): "))
Input str (text): text text #Вводим text text
'text text'
>>> float(raw_input("Input f (32): "))
Input f (32): 598 #Вводим 598
598.0
```

А еще можете пользоваться try: (except:) для обработок ошибок.

Если вам нужно вводить и текст и цифры и всё подряд, то пользуйтесь вторым моим приведенным вариантом, там прокатит всё и пустое значение и цифры:

```
>>> str(raw_input("Input str (text): "))
Input str (text): text text #Вводим text text
'text text'
```

А так он ожидает только лишь цифру.

Comment: Спасибо, trec. Я просто недавно начал изучать Python и еще не все понимаю.
Оставил просто raw_input(), но тогда возникает ошибка в математической формуле. Можете показать пример когда при неверном вводе, другие значения кроме указанных не принимаются?
Для float(raw_input()) применимы только целые и дробные числа?

Comment: Да, только целые и дробные.  
...при неверном вводе, другие значения кроме указанных не принимаются?... не совсем понял что вы хотите.  
Можно сделать либо как в ниже примере написали, либо подробнее опишите задачу.

Comment: Извиняюсь, под "указанными" я имел ввиду как раз таки int, float, то есть если бы была введена буква, float(raw_input()) выдал бы ошибку.

Comment: Ну можно еще проверку сделать if, или использовать регулярные выражения, для выявления чего угодно кроме цифр, и далее вырезать все кроме цифр, или просто известь о том что там кроме цифр еще что-то есть. Но это уже усложнение, которое мне кажется не нужно вам. Пробуйте воспользоваться примерами выше, они функциональные и работают.

Answer (score 4):

Можно обернуть ввод в try-except, как указали ответом выше и подставлять дефолтное значение, если будет введено что-то отличное от цифры, добавлю просто пример:

```
val = 0.0
try:
    val = float(raw_input())
except ValueError:
    val = 1.0
```

Тогда лучше так:

```
def get_float():
    val = 0.0
    try: 
        val = float(raw_input()) #в версии Py3k просто input()
    except ValueError: 
        val = 1.0
    return val
```

Дважды делать return не к чему на мой взгляд:)

Comment: Отличный пример +1, позволю себе ваш пример оформить функцией, если напишите более функциональную, я свою удалю.  
    <code>def fun(val=1):
      try:
        return val = float(raw_input("We accept only numeric values: "))
      except ValueError:
        print "Apply a default value"
        return val</code>  
Эту функцию можно использовать для именно вода, передавая ей значение по умолчанию если кто-то ввёл не в верном формате значение. Обратно получите чётко значение в нужном вам формате.

Comment: С return согласен, однако я акцентировал внимание на передаче параметров, чтобы значением по умолчанию можно было управлять.  
    <code><pre>  
    def fun(val=1):
      try:
        val = float(raw_input("We accept only numeric values: "))
      except ValueError:
        print "Apply a default value"
      return val</pre></code>

Comment: Да, я понял, последний вариант самый удачный с точки зрения задачи. Кстати, лучше использовать отступы в 4 пробела(по PEP), хотя понятное дело, что это просто рекомендации.

Answer (score 2):

Всем большое спасибо! У меня всё получилось.

```
 
def fun():
    while 1:
        try:
            val = float(raw_input("Введите число: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print "Вводить нужно только числа!"
    return val
```

После ввода буквы или пустого значения, запрос на ввод повторяется как я и хотел!